# Data conversion for ARM platform (from x86/x64)

Tags: c++, c, arm

We have developed win32 application for x86 and x64 platform. We want to use the same application on ARM platform. Endianness will vary for ARM platform i.e. ARM platform uses Big endian format in general. So we want to handle this in our application for our device.

For e.g. // In x86/x64,  `int nIntVal = 0x12345678`
In ARM,  `int nIntVal = 0x78563412`

How values will be stored for the following data types in ARM?

1. double
2. char array i.e. char chBuffer[256]
3. int64

Please clarify this.

Regards,
Raphel

Comment: While some processors can be run as big endian, ARM was originally little endian.  Recent processors can typically be run as either big or little endian.  Are you sure your target is big endian?

Comment: It appears that you're new to porting to other platforms.  Let me make a book recommendation: [Write Portable Code](http://nostarch.com/wpc.htm).  The free chapter even talks about endianness.  It's a great book and covers many of the issues that you'll face.

Comment: ARM is normally deployed in little-endian configuration, same as x86.  Is this an embedded processor you're porting to, configured for networking applications?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Endianess only matters for register <-> memory operations.

In a register there is no endianess. If you put

```
int nIntVal = 0x12345678
```

in your code it will have the same effect on any endianess machine.

all IEEE formats (`float`, `double`) are identical in all architectures, so this does not matter.

You only have to care about endianess in two cases:

a) You write integers to files that have to be transferable between the two architectures.
Solution: Use the `hton*, ntoh*` family of converters, use a non-binary file format (e.g. XML) or a standardised file format (e.g. SQLite).

b) You cast integer pointers.

```
int a = 0x1875824715;
char b = a;
char c = *(char *)&a;
if (b == c) {
    // You are working on Little endian
}
```

The latter code by the way is a handy way of testing your endianess at runtime.

Arrays and the likes if you use `write, fwrite` falimies of calls to transfer them you will have no problems unless they contain integers: then look above.

`int64_t`: look above. Only care if you have to store them binary in files or cast pointers.

Comment: @MitchWheat Yes. `hton*` and the likes actually stand for host-to-network and are designed for interoperability.

Comment: in fact, some old ARM compilers used to store `double` values in "mixed-endian" format - split in two little-endian words with the most significant word stored first.

Answer (score 0):

(Sergey L., above, says, taht you mostly don't have to care for the byte order. He is right, with at least 1 exception: I assumed you want to convert binary data from one platform to the other ...)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness has a good overview.

In short:

- Little endian means, the least significant byte is stored first (at the lowest address)
- Big endian means the most significant byte is stored first

The order in which array elements are stored is not affected (but the byte order in array elements, of course)

So

- char array is unchanged
- int64 - byte order is reversed compared to x86

With regard to the floating point format, consider http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness#Floating-point_and_endianness. Generally it seems to obey the same rules of endianness as the integer format, but there is are exceptions for older ARM platforms. (I've no first hand experience of that).

Generally I'd suggest, test your conversion of primitive types by controlled experiments first.

Also consider, that compilers might use different padding in structs (a topic you haven't addressed yet).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In 98% cases you don't need to care about endianness. Unless you need to transfer some data between systems of different endiannness, or read/write some endian-sensitive file format, you should not bother with it. And even in those cases, you can write your code to perform properly when compiled under any endianness.

From Rob Pike's ["The byte order fallacy"](http://commandcenter.blogspot.com/2012/04/byte-order-fallacy.html) post:

> Let's say your data stream has a little-endian-encoded 32-bit integer.
>   Here's how to extract it (assuming unsigned bytes):
>
> ```
> i = (data[0]<<0) | (data[1]<<8) | (data[2]<<16) | (data[3]<<24);
> ```
>
> If it's big-endian, here's how to extract it:
>
> ```
> i = (data[3]<<0) | (data[2]<<8) | (data[1]<<16) | (data[0]<<24);
> ```
>
> Both these snippets work on any machine, **independent** of the machine's
>   byte order, independent of alignment issues, independent of just about
>   anything. They are totally portable, given unsigned bytes and 32-bit
>   integers.

Comment: +1, I think it mostly matters if you are writing communication software including network stacks where endianness is dictated by definition.

Comment: The linked rant is 98% irrelevant as an answer. Endianness issues *do* exist. If you wanted to challenge the OP's requirement to handle endianness, it should have been as a comment.

Answer (score 0):

The arm is little endian, it has two big endian variants depending on architecture, but it is better to just run native little endian, the tools and volumes of code out there are more fully tested in little endian mode.

Endianness is just one factor in system engineering if you do your system engineering it all works out, no fears, no worries.  Define your interfaces and code to that design.  Assuming for example that one processors endianness automatically results in having to byteswap is a bad assumption and will bite you eventually.  You will end up having to swap an even number of times to undo other bad assumptions that cause a swap (ideally swapping zero times of course rather than 2 or 4 or 6, etc times).  If you have any endian concerns at all when writing code you should write it endian independent.

Since some ARMs have BE32 (word invariant) and the newer arms BE8 (byte invariant) you would have to do even more work to try to make something generic that also tries to compensate for little intel, little arm, BE32 arm and BE8 arm.    Xscale tends to run big endian natively but can be run as little endian to reduce the headaches.  You may be assuming that because an ARM clone is big endian then all are big endian, another bad assumption.